# CodeIgniter multiple db connection not fetching data from second db

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-database

One is the default and the other one is the second DB which I need only in few controllers to maintain the orders coming through the system. Here is the code, my `database.php` file is as follows:

Here is my configuration:

```
`$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'carbiz',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => 'web_',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
$db['abcd'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'sale2',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => 'web_',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);`
```

Here is My Controller

```
public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $this->otherdb = $this->load->database('abcd', TRUE);`
 }
```

Now In One Function in same controller which uses the second db

```
function add_scondary()
 {   
     $val=$this->otherdb->select('title')->get('products');
     print_r("here");
     print_r($val); 
 }
```

const CI_VERSION = '3.1.7';

Comment: what error is coming?

Comment: None it's just printing the "here" from function call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help You :**

First you have to define a `public` or `private` variable `$otherdb` like this

```
public $otherdb; 
public function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();
   $this->otherdb = $this->load->database('abcd', TRUE);
}  


function add_scondary()
 {    
     $data = $this->otherdb->get('products')->result();
     print_r(data);
 }
```

**The better way** to use different database with same connection :

*You don’t need to create separate database configurations if you only need to use a different database on the same connection. You can switch to a different database when you need to, like this:*

```
$this->db->db_select('sale2');
$data['abcd'] = $this->db->get('products')->result();
```

Comment: Call to a member function result() on boolean from above code

Comment: make sure variable u define match with $this->variable_name ; pls show you code

Comment: `$this->db->db_select('sale2');
         $data['abcd'] = $this->db->get('products')->result();
         print_r("here");
         print_r($data['abcd']);`

Comment: this is the code i have removed the load_database code

Comment: what is your table name is it `products` or `web_products`

Comment: `products` from database->sale2

Comment: 'dbprefix' => 'web_',

Comment: both the code working for me, i have tested and used so many times always works, make sure since u have dbprefix defined in ur database configuration

Comment: yup that was the problem mate i copied the first db array and changed it and forgot to remove the prefix so there was no prefix in the second db hence the error

Comment: pls check my answer as green if its help you and also do upvote my answer